# HIVE PROPERTIES settings

Tags: hive, data-retrieval

I have a dataset in a csv file . I have created a table in HIVE with two fields id and user id.  And using select query I retrieved my data . It shows id , user id and NULL. I want only id and user id to be displayed . Could anyone please help me to solve this issue

Sample data;
116 Justin
582 Ivan
.....
.....

### queries:

hive> create table hive_comments (id string, userid string) row format delimited fields terminated by ',' ;

hive> load data local inpath 'home/edureka/Documents/Project/dataDec-12-2015.csv' into table hive_comments;

hive> select * from hive_comments;

Result:

116 Justin NULL
582 Ivan NULL
.....
.....

How to remove null from this. Please help me to solve this issue.

Many Thanks

Comment: You have to better show your data. The example of data you give the numbers and names are separated by spaces, not by ';'.

Comment: There could be ',' at the end of record in your data set like this `116,Justin,` `582,Ivan,`

Answer (score 0):

Provide a single row of your input data ..we can only guess otherwise.